# Simplest/fastest way of ordering mysql output in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am pulling data from database to show it with PHP in table. How to show this data descending from x-level from highest to lowest?

An example output of code given below is

[image]

```
function check() {

    $function_Query="SELECT user, stone, iron, gold, diamond FROM xraydeath WHERE (diamond/(stone+iron+gold)) >= 0.03";
    $function_Ask = mysql_query($function_Query) or die(mysql_error());

        echo '<table cellpadding="5">
        <tr align="center">
        <td><strong>user</strong></td>
        <td><strong>x-level</strong></td>
        <td><strong>stone</strong></td>
        <td><strong>iron</strong></td>
        <td><strong>gold</strong></td>
        <td><strong>diamond</strong></td>
        </tr>';

    while($function_Result = mysql_fetch_array($function_Ask)){

        $user = $function_Result['user'];
        $stone = $function_Result['stone'];
        $iron = $function_Result['iron'];
        $gold = $function_Result['gold'];
        $diamond = $function_Result['diamond'];
        $level = round(($diamond / ($stone + $iron + $gold)), 4) * 100;

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $user . '</td>
              <td>' . $level . '</td>
              <td>' . $stone . '</td>
              <td>' . $iron . '</td>
              <td>' . $gold . '</td>
              <td>' . $diamond . '</td>';

        echo '</tr>';

            }
echo '</tr></table>';

}

check();
```

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add " `ORDER BY (diamond/(stone+iron+gold)) DESC`" to your SQL query.

Comment: Thank you! Working example: `SELECT user, stone, iron, gold, diamond FROM xraydeath WHERE (diamond/(stone+iron+gold)) >= 0.0 ORDER BY (diamond/(stone+iron+gold)) DESC`